# Crime lords and valuables

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, language, cryptic-clues, geography

> 1. Lost consciousness's rate of return is Spanish valuables in Swedish valuables. (5)
> 2. The light side running a confused *non-gay*. (6)
> 3. Stirring a *Malay T* for a grateful Spanish spirit. (6)
> 4. Dear Masalas, *confounded by* a Russian gift with an Arab greeting. (11)
> 5. Actor Martin messed up or actor Smith with no head. (4)
> 6. Returning in noble elongated French good stuff. (4)
> 7. Let Serbian mixologists have Oriental doughnut parts.  (10)
> 8. Polish colony is a universal donor and a poker commentator in a Korean automobile (7)
> 9. A rabid janitor shows muscle and passport to a Czech revolutionary. (7)
> 10. New York crime lord or Latin country meets a gaseous end. (7)

What are we listing?

---

Edit: Rechecked a rules and changed some clues (in *italics*) to better conform to the puzzle format. Thanks for @ChrisCudmore for pointing it out.

Comment: 2 and 3 are much more solvable now.  No way I would have got them before the edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>I've only solved some of the clues, but I believe the answer is...</strike>

Complete! (I think). Props to Chris Cudmore and Mohirl for figuring out 2, 3 and 7.

> **Former capitals of the world!**

1. Lost consciousness's rate of return is Spanish valuables in Swedish valuables. (5)

> Lost consciousness = KO
> Rate of Return = ROR
> Spanish valuable = Oro (Gold)
> Swedish valuable = Kr (Krona, the national currency)
> Oro in Kr = Koror.
> **Koror** is the former capital of Palau.

2. The light side running a confused non-gay. (6)
   (Credit to **Chris Cudmore**)

> Yangon is an anagram of non-gay.
> Yang is the light side of yin-yang 
>  On = Running (as in "Is the fridge on?")
> **Yangon** is the former capital of Myanmar.

3. Stirring a Malay T for a grateful Spanish spirit. (6) (Credit to **Chris Cudmore**)

> Almaty is an anagram of Malay T.
> Alma is soul in Spanish.
> TY = Thank You.
> Alma + TY = "grateful Spanish spirit"
> **Almaty** is the former capital of Kazakhstan.

4. Dear Masalas, a Russian gift with an Arab greeting. (11)

> Dear Masalas is an anagram for Dar es Salaam
> Dar is gift in Russian.
> Salaam is an Arab greeting.
> **Dar es Salaam** is the former capital of Tanzania.

5. Actor Martin messed up or actor Smith with no head. (4)

> Dean Martin was an actor and singer. Aden is Dean scrambled.
> Jaden Smith is an actor and rapper. Aden is Jaden without the head (the letter J).
> **Aden** is the former capital of Yemen.

6. Returning in noble elongated French good stuff. (4)

> Bonn is in the phrase "returning i**n nob**le" backwards
> Bon is good in French.
> Bonn is "bon" elongated.
> **Bonn** is the former capital of Germany.

7. Let Serbian mixologists have Oriental doughnut parts. (10) (Credit to **Mohirl**)

> East Berlin is an anagram of 'Let Serbian'.
> East = Oriental
> Berliner is a doughnut-like cake
> Berlin is part of Berliner.
> Oriental doughnut part = East Berlin.
> **East Berlin** is the former capital of (East) Germany.

8. Polish colony is a universal donor and a poker commentator in a Korean automobile (7)

> Colony in Polish = Kolonia
> Universal Donor = O-
> Korean automobile = Kia
> Poker commentator = Lon (McEachern)
> Universal Donor and Lon in Kia = Kolonia
> **Kolonia** is the former capital of Micronesia

9. A rabid janitor shows muscle and passport to a Czech revolutionary. (7)

> Rabid janitor has Abidjan in it
> Abs are muscles
> Your passport is an ID
> Jan (Palach) was a Czech political protester who set himself on fire
> **Abidjan** is the former capital of Cote d'Ivoire.

10. New York crime lord or Latin country meets a gaseous end. (7)

> Colombo is a prominent NY crime family
> Colombia + gaseous end (O = Oxygen) = Colombo.
> **Colombo** is the former capital of Sri Lanka.

Comment: Where's the anagram indicator in 4?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Ahh you're right, it's missing from #4... my bad

Comment: @NudgeNudge : Edit in the other answers for completeness (with credit) and take the win.

Comment: Okey! Great job everyone! :)

Comment: All correct! You get the tick!

Answer (score 4):

2.

> YANGON (former capital of Myanmar) Anagram of NON-GAY. YANG (light side of yin-yang, + ON as in "Is the fridge on?".)

3.

> ALMATY (former capital of Kazakhstan)  Anagram of MALAY T  or, ALMA is a Spanish Soul, saying TY (Thank You)

8.

> K(O)(LON)IA (O is the universal blood donor, LON McEachern is the voice of poker, inside KIA)

Answer (score 4):

Number 5 is

> Aden

Actor Martin messed up or actor Smith with no head

> Dean (Martin) messed up is Aden; Jaden (Smith) with no head is Aden

Number 7 is

> East Berlin (former capital of East Germany)

Let Serbian mixologists have Oriental doughnut parts. (10)

> Anagram of 'Let Serbian'. Struggling with the second half though. Although a Berliner is a doughnut like cake, so an Oriental doughnut could be an E Berliner.